# Как правильно модифицировать базовый конструткор?

Tags: c#, ооп, наследование

Мучаю наследование. Стакнулся на моменте использования конструктора базового класса в производном.

Базовый класс:

```
namespace ConsoleApp12
{
    class Employee
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public float Pay { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public Employee()
        {

        }
        public Employee(string name, int age, float pay)
        {
            Name = name;
            Age = age;
            Pay=pay;
        }

    }
}
```

Производный:

```
namespace ConsoleApp12
{
    class Manager : Employee
    {
        public int SalaryIndex { get; set; }
        public Manager(int salIndex) : base(name, age, pay)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Получаю ошибку: [image: Ошибка]

Кто может объяснить что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы вызываете конструктор базовогo класса, передавая туда в качестве параметров переменные, которых в этом месте нет.

```
class Manager : Employee 
{
  public int SalaryIndex { get; set; } 

  public Manager(int salIndex) : base() 
  {
    SalaryIndex = salIndex;
  }

  public Manager(int salIndex, string name, int age, float pay) : base(name, age, pay) 
  {
    SalaryIndex = salIndex;
  }
}
```

Comment: Все понял, отложилось. Спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 1):

Если в потомке уже определены некоторые параметры базового класса (например, есть значения по умолчанию, либо значения вычисляются из других параметров), то, если эти свойства не приватные, их можно инициализировать в конструкторе потомка.

```
class Manager : Employee 
{
    public int SalaryIndex { get; set; } 

    public Manager(int salIndex) : base() 
    {
        SalaryIndex = salIndex;
        Name = "Имя по умолчанию";
        Age = 20;
        Pay = 1000 * Age;
    }
}
```